# ASP.NET MVC Value cannot be null Parameter name: httpContext

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have downloaded Storefront ASP.NET MVC application. When I try to run the application, I get the following exception:

> ArgumentNullException - **Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
>   httpContext**

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of odd.  The HttpContext houses things such as request and response, cache, cookies, etc.  If you are running the project from the perspective of a web site it generally would not be null.  Is this error coming up when referencing it in the global?  It is possible that you are trying to get to it before it exists in the requests life cycle.  Can you post more of the error?

Comment: I downloaded the source code, opened in Visual Studio 2008, build the solution successfully, ran the project, and it threw the exception at this line in Site.Master page : <%Html.RenderAction<PersonalizationController>(x => x.Summary());%>. 
Here is the top line in StackTrace -    at System.Web.Routing.RequestContext..ctor(HttpContextBase httpContext, RouteData routeData) 
and the Exception Message: Value cannot be null Parameter name:httpContext.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're getting the latest source code [Kona](https://mvcsamples.svn.codeplex.com/svn/trunk). PersonalizationController isn't part of the current codebase.

Comment: How do i get the latest source code Kona? I mean How can I download it? Do I really need it for this Storefront application and to resolve the error I am getting?